# Terraform Cannot locate module locally: Unknown reason

Tags: azure, terraform, infrastructure-as-code

i am encountering with the issue  which is terraform cant not locate the module locally.  I really appreciate your advise. Thanks in advance.

Error: `#Warning:(7, 1) Cannot locate module locally: Unknown reason`

## project structure

[image]

```
#The module is called in the "main.tf" which is located env_prod dir
module "az_resource_groups" {
  source="../module/az_resource_groups"
  context_object  = local.context_object 
  resource_groups = var.resource_groups  
  tags            = var.tags
}
```

Comment: Where is the module on your machine?

Comment: Ok, so you have multiple modules under the `az_resource_groups` directory so you will have to invoke each one of those separately.

Comment: If the module code is in `create_rg`, you would need to specify that as well as `*.tf` config files aren't in `az_resource_groups` directory. Try with `source="../module/az_resource_groups/create_rg"`..

Comment: Hello @MarkoE, Thank you so much for your reply. I have tried  with the both path of the module but still i am facing the same issue "unresolved module" ->Cannot locate module locally: Unknown reason". "../module/az_resource_groups/create_rg" "../module/az_resource_groups/create_rg/*.tf"

Comment: The second one surely will not work.

Comment: Even the first one is not working @MarkoE. I am just stuck into this for further stepping

Comment: Just out of curiosity: did you run `terraform init`?

Comment: I am using git ci/cd and  the console is saying-> you run "terraform init" in the future.
Terraform has been successfully initialized!
$ terraform valida

Comment: I believe this is an IntelliJ IDEA error message rather than a Terraform error message; see [IDEA-287371](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-287371/Terraform-cannot-locate-module-locally-unknown-reason) for some discussion about it.

Comment: If your module has been downloaded from the terraform registry, you can prepend 'registry.terraform.io/' to the beginning of the url - ie, 'source  = "registry.terraform.io/terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"'.  Otherwise you have to change the module path to a local relative path (ie, 'source = "./terraform/modules"').  See https://lightrun.com/answers/vladrassokhin-intellij-hcl-cannot-locate-module-locally